# jQuery - Get value of radio or text input

Tags: jquery

I have the code retrieving the `checked` radio `value` into the `#donation` text field however I want to set up an additional `readonly` that shows the selected value whether it was a radio or what was keyed up in the text field. At any given time I want the last selected radio or newly keyed value to display in `#donation_confirm`.

```js
$("#donation").click(function () {
  $(this).val("");
  });
$("#donation").keyup(function() {
  $(this).closest("div").addClass("donation--active");
  $("input:radio[name=donation]").each(function() {
    $(this).prop("checked", false);
  });
});
$('input[type="radio"]').on("change", function() {
  $("#donation").closest("div").removeClass("donation--active");
  $("#donation, #donation_confirm").val(
    this.checked ?
    this.value :
    $('input[type="radio"][name="' + this.name + '"]:checked').val()
  );
});
$('input[type="radio"]').trigger("change");
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 30px;
  min-width: 320px;
  max-width: 540px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.inline-radio {
  font-size: 19px;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.inline-radio div {
  border: 1px solid #ededed;
  margin-top: -1px;
  margin-left: -1px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
}

.inline-radio div:last-child {
  color: #b6b6b6;
  padding: 0 0.9rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.inline-radio input[type="radio"] {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  opacity: 0;
}

.inline-radio input[type="text"] {
  color: #b6b6b6;
  font-size: inherit;
  margin-left: 0.3rem;
  display: flex;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background: #0000ff00
}

.inline-radio label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: #b6b6b6;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.inline-radio input:checked+label {
  background: #d81b60;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #fff;
}

.donation--active {
  background: #d81b60;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #fff !important;
}

.donation--active input {
  color: #fff !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="inline-radio">
  <div><input type="radio" value="5" name="donation"><label>$5</label></div>
  <div><input type="radio" value="25" name="donation" checked><label>$25</label></div>
  <div><input type="radio" value="50" name="donation"><label>$50</label></div>
  <div><input type="radio" value="100" name="donation"><label>$100</label></div>
  <div><span>$</span><input id="donation" value="" name="donation" type="text"></div>
</div>
<div><span>$</span><input id="donation_confirm" value="" name="donation" type="text" readonly></div>
```

Comment: May be you want the 'input' event. It triggers every time the input value changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add a line to your function:

```
$("#donation").keyup(function() {
  $(this).closest("div").addClass("donation--active");
  $("input:radio[name=donation]").each(function() {
    $(this).prop("checked", false);
  });
  $('#donation_confirm').val($(this).val()) // add this line
});
```

this detects the keyup, and updates the input field with the new value; you might want to limit the input to numeric only

here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/503n8tfq/)